# X-Frame-Options исключение для определенных сайтов

Tags: html, iis

Можно ли сделать для некоторых сайтов исключение заголовка `X-Frame-Options`?
Т.е. у нас к примеру сайт на веб сервере IIS который отдаёт такой заголовок `X-Frame-Options: DENY`, а нам нужно чтобы пара других сайтов которые находятся на других доменах могли загружать наш сайт через iframe.

Comment: Можно попробовать посмотреть на заголовок http referer - там должен храниться источник запроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X-Frame-Options` [морально устарел](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options).

Используйте заголовок [`Content-Security-Policy` с директивой `frame-ancestors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives#frame-ancestors), он позволяет перечислить несколько сайтов:

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' example.com *.example.net
```

И добавьте [`X-Content-Security-Policy`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy) для поддержки IE.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!